# get the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error

Tags: swift, mapkit, coordinates, eventkit

Im using google places api to and use the coordinates to put an annotation on an apple maps.

What I want to do now is to translate coordinates to name and address and use it for the Ekreminder. This is my code so far but i get the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when i try to run it:

```
    addLocationReminderViewController.name = self.mapItemData.placemark.name

    // Construct the address
    let dic = self.mapItemData.placemark.addressDictionary as Dictionary!
    let city = dic["City"] as! String
    let state = dic["State"] as! String
    let country = dic["Country"] as! String
    addLocationReminderViewController.address = "\(city), \(state), \(country)"
}
```

edit this is how im getting the info:

```
                    if data != nil{
                    let dic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as!  NSDictionary

                    let lat = dic["results"]?.valueForKey("geometry")?.valueForKey("location")?.valueForKey("lat")?.objectAtIndex(0) as! Double
                    let lon = dic["results"]?.valueForKey("geometry")?.valueForKey("location")?.valueForKey("lng")?.objectAtIndex(0) as! Double
                    let point = MKPointAnnotation()
                    point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
                    point.title = self.resultsArray[indexPath.row]
                    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: point.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(point)
                        self.mapView.selectAnnotation(point, animated: true)
                        //
                        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: point.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
                        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
                        self.mapItemData = mapItem
                        //
                    })
```

Comment: Do you really mean `Dictionary!`?

Answer (score 0):

You are 'blindly' casting dictionary references for "City", "State" and "Country" to `String` using `as!`.  If any one of them doesn't exist in the dictionary or isn't a string then you get your fatal error.

How do you plan to handle a malformed dictionary?  You could use

```
if let city    = dic["City"]    as? String,
   let state   = dic["State"]   as? String,
   let country = dic["Country"] as? String {
  // you now have your values
  addLocationReminderViewController.address = "\(city), \(state), \(country)"
}
else {
 // something is wrong
}
```